# Code_Cave Example C Programming

Tags: c, security

I was wondering, for infosec demonstration purposes and such, if it were possible to create a code cave manually in C programming?

Wikipedia states:

> A code cave is a series of null bytes in a process's memory

I have tried this:

```
char *cave = malloc(10000);
 register int i;
 for(i=0;i<999;i++){
  cave[i]='\0';
 }
```

And EDB shows that it is all NULL bytes, but cave_miner (latest version from GutHUB) does not seem to find the cave when I try for 10000 or even 100 bytes in length. Is my GCC removing it somehow? I don't get any output from GCC when compiling. I am using GCC version 8.2.0 (Debian).

Thank you in advance for your help.
Again, I would just like to demonstrate a code cave injection attack without using anyone else's binary, even if it's open source.
~kp

Answer (score 1):

**Cave_miner** --> Search for code cave in **binaries** (i.e. elf files, obj files etc)

The code you have presented will allocate 10000 bytes of `cave` in the **RAM**. Specifically in the *heap*.

That is why it is not found.

Comment: Thank you. So, when the loader puts the binary into RAM before execution, those null bytes are there. But, Cave_Miner only looks at the static binary and not in a dynamic way. Is that what you mean?